# Why don't the deinit get called when i go to another view?

Tags: swift, class, memory-leaks

I have a object for my viewcontroller in a navigationcontroller that don't get deinitialized when i go back and i wonder why.

This is the class

```
class MyLeague {
    var league : League?
    var fixtures : [Fixture] = []
    var teams : [Team] = []
    var standings : [Standing] = []

    init() {
        print("Creating")
    }
    deinit {
        print("Deallocating")
    }
}
```

Here is how i create it in the viewcontroller

```
let selectedLeague = MyLeague()
```

And this way i set the property

```
    APIManager.shared.request(url: url, onSuccess: { [weak self] (data) in
        do {
            let fixtureData = try JSONDecoder().decode(FixturesResponse.self, from: data)
            self?.selectedLeague.fixtures = fixtureData.api.fixtures
            self?.competitionTableView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Is your viewcontroller still present in navigation stack? Is there another reference to it somewhere?

Comment: so you go from VC1 to VC2? And this `selectedLeague` is inside VC2? ok. Does VC2 itself also get de-initialized? If not then that's main problem.

Comment: Please rewrite your answer and include the the line of code where you had a strong reference. That way your answer would be complete and won't get deleted. PS: I didn't delete your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using Instruments to find any retain cycles in your code.

You can access it from Product -> Profile Then select the Allocations tool and use it to track which object is calling your class at that frame of time when you navigate. Hope this helped.